# Moving out of a shared reference on a generic type

Tags: generics, rust, traits, move-semantics

I'm trying to create a function that takes a `&[Vec<u64>]` and returns vector of tuple "coordinates" for the largest `i64` in each row using iterators. I have it working on concrete types, but I want it to be generic over `T` and bounded to iterable types. My code so far:

```
fn find_largest_per_row<T>(input: &[T]) -> Vec<(usize, usize)> 
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = u64>,
{
    input
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(r, v)| {
            v.into_iter()
                .enumerate()
                .max_by_key(|&(_, v)| v)
                .map(|(c, _)| (r, c))
                .unwrap()
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}
```

I'm getting:

```
cannot move out of `*v` which is behind a shared reference
```

How do I resolve this? I realize `T` is a reference so I tried `.cloned()`, but that didn't work.

Also, for `IntoIterator<Item=u64>`, do I need to specify `u64` or can I provide something more generic?

Comment: You can' have `T: IntoIterator<Item=u64>`, because `T` is in a `&[T]`, so it's always behind a shared reference where `IntoIterator` can't take `self` to move the receiver into the iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IntoIterator::into_iter` takes `self`, which means it consumes (or *moves*) the object.

You have added the bound `T: IntoIterator` so, since that's the only `IntoIterator` around, the compiler will use `T`'s implementation. Calling `into_iter` on `T` will always move the value, which is not ok because the function has only been given a reference to it and `T` might not be `Copy` - in fact, for `Vec` it definitely isn't.

But `IntoIterator` is also implemented for most references to iterable types, for example `&Vec<T>`, where the item is a reference too. These are ok to move because references are `Copy`, so the original data is left intact when they are moved.

You can change your function signature like this:

```
fn find_largest_per_row<'a, T>(input: &'a [T]) -> Vec<(usize, usize)>
where
    &'a T: IntoIterator<Item = &'a u64>,
{
    input
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(r, v)| {
            v.into_iter()
                .enumerate()
                .max_by_key(|&(_, v)| v)
                .map(|(c, _)| (r, c))
                .unwrap()
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}
```

To answer the second question, yes, you can make the item generic. Instead of specifying a concrete type, you can omit it and then specify the bounds that the code requires. You are moving it by value, so it needs to be `Copy` (or else you need to change the code to clone it and make it `Clone` instead), and you are using [`max_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/fn.max_by_key.html), which requires it to be `Ord`. The function signature would then be:

```
fn find_largest_per_row<'a, T>(input: &'a [T]) -> Vec<(usize, usize)>
where
    &'a T: IntoIterator,
    <&'a T as IntoIterator>::Item: Ord + Copy,
```

---

See also:

- [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules)

Comment: Thanks, this was a great answer! I've never had more trouble learning a language than Rust. Am I missing some fountain of knowledge or is this just a lot of trail and error?

Comment: @marcantonio There is definitely a lot to learn. Like anything else, it starts to come easier with practice, but Rust's learning curve is steep - especially at the start.